# Power BI - How do I put a filter on a card visual based on the value in another column

Tags: filtering, powerbi

I am brand new to Power BI. I have detail data that looks like

Server    Application
Server1   App1
Server1   App2
Server2   App1
Server2   App3

My manager wants to get some analytics. The first was Distinct # of Servers. I was able to do this with a card Visualization.

The second is # of Apps using more than 1 processor. I am able to make a Card Visualization of the # of Distinct Apps and I can use Server as a filter, but the only options I have are that the Server is one of the Servers in the data or if I use Advanced Filtering it only has text options like Contains, Does Not Contain, etc. There are no count options available. How can I accomplish this seemingly simple task?

Thanks,

Dick

Comment: Somehow the data didn't come out the way I typed it in:

Server   Application    are column headers
Server1 App1             is the first data row
Server1 App2             is the second data row
Server2 App1             is the third data row
Server2 App3             is the fourth data row

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your problem you can proceed like this:
[Table containing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhQ4l.png)

You should build a measure like that:
CountOfApp = COUNT(Table1[Application])

then you can use it to filter servers with more than x application like this:
[See Visual level filters on the selected visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inkf9.png)

Hope that helps!